# Automate creation and deployment of SSRS report from single table query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

What is the most efficient way to automate both creation and deployment of simple SSRS reports from one underlying query?

An example query might look like

```
SELECT Name, ID, Date FROM Errorlog
```

Query could contain quite a few columns and anywhere from 1 to 1 million rows.

The business purpose behind this question is that I have a sizable number of report queries that need to go out as SSRS reports.  I also need the capacity to turn any query I write instantly (or within a matter of seconds) into a simple SSRS report.  Unfortunately, doing it through BIDS manually (using toolbox items and creating datasets is cumbersome, slow and unnecessarily repetitive.  The only thing I am concerned with is making sure interactive page height/width is zero (to allow scrolling) and that columns are autosized.

How would you accomplish this in a way that is smooth and repeatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I don't think SSRS will not be very good at this. Specifically on two points this may be troublesome.

First, the number of **rows** may become a problem. One million results is typically a bit much for reporting services 2008 (though it does depend on the context a bit), it's much better at displaying either aggregated data, or a limited number (up to a few thousand - though again: depending on context) of data rows.

Second, a dynamic number of **columns** being returned by the SQL side will be a problem. There's only two ways around this that I know of:

- Have a denormalized data set with a fixed number of columns, and one or more columns that contain the grouping. Then use a [matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to generate columns dynamically in SSRS. This does have a considerable performance impact.
- Generate the RDL dynamically. There's [information on the schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155062%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to do this, and if you create a good starting point it's very possible. After generating the RDL you'll have to execute it - how to do that depends on your specific setup.

Bottom line is that *I wouldn't recommend using SSRS for the task you describe*. Consider other technologies that may be better up to this task, e.g. SSIS packages, or perhaps another custom made or third party tool?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd utilize 'Access Data Projects' which have a wizard for creating report.. that is then easy to upsize to Reporting Services. Right-click IMPORT into a solution full of RDL, and it prompts for MS Access file.

You can easily make a couple of columns into a report using an Access wizard, and then upsize to SSRS.. I've done it hundreds upon hundreds of times like this.