# SSRS automation

Tags: reporting-services

I need to build many different reports with exactly the same simple structure from many different datasets defined by many different queries.  Specifically, I need a report which shows, in table form, the information stored in a table.

Is there a way of automatically generating these reports?  Can I use VBA or something to, for each table:
- set up a dataset based on the query "select [tablename].* from [tablename]
- title the report from [tablename]
- display all fields retrieved in a table?

Many thanks in advance
Nick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate creation and deployment of SSRS report from single table query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515353/automate-creation-and-deployment-of-ssrs-report-from-single-table-query)

Comment: @user1945205 - Are you looking for a one time creation of these reports, with a little bit of help by hand, or is this for ongoing automatic report creation? If the latter, see the question Jeroen linked to. If the former, please update the question.

Comment: Could this be done better with one or two generic reports? Sounds like a lot of overhead to maintain 1 report per table.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have seen to this is the Data Profiler reports produced by the Kimball Group:

http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-and-business-intelligence-resources/data-warehouse-books/booksmdwt/

You can make a mashup based on their "2 Columnlist" and "3 ColumnDetails" reports to get what you want.